# Julia Module calling User Defined Function

Tags: function, methods, julia

I have a module which builds up some levels of abstraction for a simulation I'd like to perform. Let's say the lowest level of abstraction is a `node` (which we build into `system`s, if we truncate this at two levels of abstraction), which is a subtype of an abstract type I define in the module. The `node`s are updated with a user-defined `update!` function.

I want the user to be able to define a new `node` and `update!` function, but the `update!` function should be callable from the module's `system_update!` function. An example is provided below:

```
module test_pack
abstract type Node end

struct System{N<:Node}
    nodes::Array{N,1}
end

function system_update!(s::System)
   update!.(s.nodes) 
end

export Node, System, system_update!
end


# import module
using Main.test_pack


# User-defined types and functions
mutable struct My_Node<:Node
    state
end
function update!(n::My_Node)
   n.state *= 2 
end


# Define system of user defined nodes
sys = System([My_Node(1), My_Node(2)])

# Run the system
system_update!(sys)
```

Running this code gives

`ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: update! not defined`

However, if I move the definition of `My_Node` and `update!` to within the module and then export `My_Node`, the code executes and return the appropriate `2,4` output.

Is there a way I can enable the type of behavior I expect, where the user defines the type and `update!` function, but the module-defined `System` can call those functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing what you want would be to set things up in such a way that the `update!` *function* is defined by the module, and the code which defines the `My_Node` type (deriving from `Node`) also defines a specific [*method*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/) extending the `update!` function.

Here, since there is no default implementation for `update!` working on an argument of abstract type `Node`, an [empty generic function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Empty-generic-functions-1) can be defined to only mark the function as "belonging" to the module, without providing any implementation.
The implementation of the `TestPack.update!(::My_Node)` method explicitly extends this function, referring to it via a fully qualified name.

```
module TestPack
abstract type Node end

struct System{N<:Node}
    nodes::Array{N,1}
end

function update! end

function system_update!(s::System)
    update!.(s.nodes)
end

export Node, System, system_update!
end


# import module
using .TestPack


# User-defined types and functions
mutable struct My_Node<:Node
    state
end

function TestPack.update!(n::My_Node)
    n.state *= 2
end


sys = System([My_Node(1), My_Node(2)])

# Run the system
system_update!(sys)
```

The code above runs without problem and yields:

```
julia> sys
System{My_Node}(My_Node[My_Node(2), My_Node(4)])
```

---

As an aside, note that it is customary in Julia to use CamelCase notations for the name of modules; in the example above, I renamed your module to `TestPack` to follow this [stylistic convention](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables/#Stylistic-Conventions-1).

The module can also be referred to as `using .TestPack` instead of `using Main.TestPack`; this is called a [relative module path](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Relative-and-absolute-module-paths-1).

Comment: Thanks for your help, that makes sense and solves the issue. I also appreciate your aside on stylistic convention.

Comment: avoid using `Any` type for the `state`. If you do not know the type ex-ante use parametric types.